# how to copy data from one column to another excluding the first record in same table?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
col1  
1   
2   
3   
4   
5   
6
```

output:

```
col2
2
3
4     
5
6
null
```

Comment: Rows in a table are like balls in a basket. There is no inherent ordering.  There is no concept of "first record (row)".  "first" only applies to a result set, the result of a SELECT with an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Pleas, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```
SELECT col1,
       LEAD(col1) OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS col2
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6;
```

Outputs:

> | COL1 | COL2 |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2 |
> | 2 | 3 |
> | 3 | 4 |
> | 4 | 5 |
> | 5 | 6 |
> | 6 |  |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d44f38d285a9a3bc024e8e234d51c814)*

Comment: But how to update this in the same table. As this is not working with update command @MT0

Comment: ID        COL1         COL2
A            1              2
B            2              3
C            3              4
D            4              5
E            5              6
F            6             NULL